# Laravel Blade extended content at bottom

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

After extending a file, the contents of the file are stuck at the bottom of the page below everything.

I wanted to extend my navbar, and have it at the top of the page, but it just defaults to bottom.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<p>This will be at top</p>
```

This problem does not occur when I just have the navbar in the file instead of extending it.

Comment: Are you making sure to use `@endsection` too?

Comment: it will be appended in the location where you have placed the yield in the layout file and also use @endsection as well

Comment: @TimLewis I forgot to use `@endsection`, but after I added it, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Working with blade templates using components and slot**

Project Structure

```
>resources
-views
--components
---base.blade.php
---navbar.blade.php
---hero.blade.php
--index.blade.php
```

base.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CasvaLabs</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">CasvaLabs</a>
        <ul>
            <a href="">
                <li>Mentors</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Library</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Pricing</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Sign in</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Sign up</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    {{-- hero --}}
    <section class="hero">
        <div class="hero-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequatur, veritatis.
        </div>
        <div class="hero-img">
            <img src="./hero-img.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

*Now lets split the **nav** into **navbar.blade.php** and **hero** into **hero.blade.php***

navbar.blade.php

```
<nav>
        <a href="#">CasvaLabs</a>
        <ul>
            <a href="">
                <li>Mentors</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Library</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Pricing</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Sign in</li>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <li>Sign up</li>
            </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

hero.blade.php

```
<section class="hero">
        <div class="hero-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequatur, veritatis.
        </div>
        <div class="hero-img">
            <img src="./hero-img.png" alt="">
        </div>
</section>
```

*Now lets create **index.blade.php** which will be rendered as our home route '/'*

index.blade.php

```
 <section>
        <h1>This is what we do:</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum pariatur, ut sed, natus hic sit minus a
            repudiandae saepe adipisci aperiam consectetur, non est necessitatibus?
        </p>
        <h1>Our Responsibilities as Ghanaians</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam obcaecati nemo consequuntur placeat illum
            tempore hic repellat accusamus veritatis consequatur.</p>
  </section>
```

**Now lets use the blade templating**

Our base.blade.php template will look like this after we have separated the nav and the hero into different *.blade.php* files

base.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CasvaLabs</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{-- because we have created navbar.blade.php this is how we call it in our base.blade.php --}} 
    <x-navbar/>

    {{-- hero --}}
     {{-- same for hero --}}
   <x-hero/>

   {{-- we use {{ $slot }} because we are inheriting from our base in the index.blade.php --}}
   {{ $slot }}
</body>

</html>
```

Now we have realized that in our ***base.blade.php*** we have replaced
`<x-navbar/>` with the whole ***navbar.blade.php*** file and same as `<x-hero/>`
and **hero.blade.php**

Finally rendering our **index.blade.php** will look like this, which is inheriting from our **base.blade.php** file

index.blade.php

```
// now we are inheriting from the base using the <x-base> tag 
<x-base>
<section>
        <h1>This is what we do:</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum pariatur, ut sed, natus hic sit minus a
            repudiandae saepe adipisci aperiam consectetur, non est necessitatibus?
        </p>
        <h1>Our Responsibilities as Ghanaians</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam obcaecati nemo consequuntur placeat illum
            tempore hic repellat accusamus veritatis consequatur.</p>
  </section>
<x-base/>
```

**Note you don't need to do** `php artisan make:controller <controller-name>` **for the above to work.**